# Ensure an element is not present with Capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara

Using Capybara, I need to assert that a form element is not present, for example, 'Then I should not see the "Username" text field'. As find throws an exception if the element isn't found, this is the best I've come up with. Is there a better way?

```rb
Then /^I should not see the "([^\"]+)" ([^\s]+) field$/ do |name, type|
  begin
    # Capybara throws an exception if the element is not found
    find(:xpath, "//input[@type='#{type}' and @name='#{name}']")
    # We get here if we find it, so we want this step to fail
    false
  rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound
    # Return true if there was an element not found exception
    true
  end 
end
```

I'm new to Capybara, so I may be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can do this by making use of capybaras has_no_selector? method combined with rspecs magic matchers. You can then use it in this way:

```
 page.should have_no_selector(:xpath, "//input[@type='#{type}' and @name='#{name}']")
```

You can see more details of the assertions you can perform on the capybara documentation page [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) under the section entitled Querying

Comment: I knew I was overlooking something obvious :)

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution prevents Capybara from waiting for the element to appear, so your tests should run faster with it. By the way, you can also do `page.should have_no_field(name)`.

Comment: Also, for anyone wondering. `page.should_not have_xpath("...")` did not work, but this method did work! Thanks!

Edit: never mind...spoke too soon

Comment: also worth noting you can use css selectors as well: have_no_selector(:css, '#my-dom-id')

Answer (score 30):

You can actually use already existing methods defined by Capybara matchers.

```
assert has_no_field?('Username')
```

Furthermore there are additional methods available the can help you in finding different types of elements in your page

```
has_link? , has_no_link?
has_button?, has_no_button?
has_field?, has_no_field?
has_checked_field?, has_no_checked_field?
has_select?, has_no_select?
```

And many more . . .

Comment: An important one to have highlighted at the top of your list is: 
`has_css?   /   has_no_css?`

Example:
`assert has_no_css?('.my-class')`
`assert has_no_css?('#my-id')`

Source:  https://devhints.io/capybara

You can also add `== false`  or `== true` if you want to be extra descriptive (though not needed)

Answer (score 16):

Here's what I am using:

```
expect(page).to have_no_css('.test')
```

Comment: thanks for this easy and clean solution. i learned to use a lot of dynamically created element ids to optimize feature specs, and this is exactly what i needed right now to get along with my test suite... thx

Answer (score 3):

I tried the solution suggested by [Derek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98078/derek-ekins), however, I ran into some false negatives.

That is

```
page.should have_no_selector(:xpath, "//input[@type='#{type}' and @name='#{name}']")
```

passes even when it should fail for some reason.

I have found success with the RSpec syntax of `raise_error`

```
expect { find(:xpath, "//input[@type='#{type}' and @name='#{name}']") }.to raise_error
```

I think this is closer to what you're asking anyway.  So I put this forward as an answer.

Comment: This! I don't even understand what have_no_selector is useful for if it doesn't wait...

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to find the element and the assert that it is not present.  Not only does this create reusable code, but the whole test won't blow up if it can't find it.

This is what I do...

define your object

```
def username
    page.find('.username')
end
```

Then interact with the object in your spec file

```
username.should be_true
```

You really shouldn't care whether or not the element is on the page (most of the time).  What you care about when you're writing the tests is whether or not you can interact with that element...that's why I define the object first, and then use 'username' to interact with it...see how much reusable code you can generate?  Now you can click, hover, assert the element is present, fill in text to the element, etc.

Also, you should definitely consider using css over xpath whenever possible. xpath is easier to break and harder to read.

Comment: Hey Whitney, the find method raises an ElementNotFoundException which the OP is trying to avoid. How does your method get around this?

Comment: Positively asserting that a tag disappeared is what Capybara's for; testing the view layer with its dynamic JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But since I am using Capybara with Minitest the accepted solution did not work for me. I thought I should add it, if someone in the same situation as me would find this question.

It is also possible to use:

`assert page.has_no_xpath?('//input[@type='#{type}' and @name='#{name}'"]')`

Answer (score 0):

**In spec file**

```
expect(@app.some_page_name.is_visible?('search_button')) == true
```

**In page file**

```
element :search_button, :xpath, "//div[@class='dummy']"
```

**In base_page file**

```
def is_visible?(value)
  begin
    eval(value).visible?
    return true
  rescue => e
    p e.message
    return false
  end
end
```